# PHP connecting to Amazon EC2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Even when I set the security group to allow all traffic, the following error keeping showing. How should I set the security rules properly?

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host '123.202.164.45' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/data.php on line 16
Failed to connect to MySQL: Host '123.202.164.45' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Comment: Question: From where are you trying to connect to the MySQL instance?  Also, are you really running MySQL from an EC2 node, or instead is it running somewhere in RDS?

Answer (score 2):

Solved, thanks! MySQL forbids remote login for the root account.

Comment: Probably for the best.